# How to extract non-intersection part of two ordered lists?

Tags: java, collections

I want to join two string lists. Both lists have a fixed order.

Problem: the 2nd list contains partially the "end" of the 1st list. I never know how many items of the end of the first list are on top of the 2nd list.

Example:

1st list:

```
testa
testb
testc
testa
testd
testg
```

2nd list:

```
testa //from 1st
testd //from 1st
testg //from 1st
textf
testc
testb
testa
```

Here you see the first elements in the 2nd list are "continued" from the 1st list. I thus want to remove these 3 items from the 2nd list and then join both lists.

Question: how is such an operation called? Probably there are already frameworks like apache-commons CollectionUtils that might perform those operations?

Comment: You could use an intermediate structure that doesn't allow dups then dump it to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it's called (although it looks a little bit like the [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), but with additional constraints) and I don't think you'll find a built-in method. But you could write it:

1. `list1` of length `n1` and `list2` of length `n2`
2. start from item `i=max(0, n1-n2)` and check if `list1(i) == list2(n1-i-1)`
3. keep incrementing `i` until you find a match
4. compare the sublists `list1(i:n1)` and `list2(0:n1-i-1)` - if they match you have found what you wanted, otherwise go back to 3

That can probably be made more efficient.